# Serialize to JSON in C# and deserialize in TS

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization, typescript

I have problem with send data between my two apps. I serialize data to JSON in C# using this code:

```
public static string SerializeToJson<T>(this T obj)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
    byte[] array = ms.ToArray();
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(array, 0, array.Length);
}
```

and then i send this using socket communication to my second application which is implemented in TypeScript. I deserialize it using:

```
JSON.parse
```

function and it works fine, but if in data is special characters for example 8211 '–' it throw exception

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 907
```

Maybe it is problem with different encoding with serialize and deserialize, but I don't know which encoding is used in JSON.parse.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you provide example of json causing error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem using convert to base64 my string and then decode it in my second application.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use [Newtonsoft Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (available from nuget).
It's easy to use and very powerfull.

```
public static string SerializeToJson<T>(this T obj)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
}
```

And you can even add some formating or what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me. The following solution also ensures the type of underlying objects. To Convert **C# object to typescript object**.

Convert your object to json format using any of the JSON libraries. (newtonsoft is most suggested one)

```
string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product); // product =new Product(); <= Product is custom class. substitute your class here
```

Pass this string to your application. (ActionResult or ajax call)

Now in the javascript access the value using Model (Razor or ajax result)

```
YourTSClass.ProcessResults('@Model') // using razor in js
```

or

```
 .done(response => {ProcessResults(response)}) // using ajax success result
```

You need not apply JSON.Parse this way.

In the typescript you can get the result by declaring the function like this.

```
public static ProcessResults(result: Product){...}
```